# Why encodeURIComponent not working if requested string contains quote?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here how we are getting user company name from session in aspx page

```
 var Details = "AgentCompanyName=" + encodeURIComponent("<%=((Agent_Html5.AgentClassLib.clsAgentSession)Session["UserSession"]).strAgentCompanyName%>");
```

above code works fine if `strAgentCompanyName` doesn't contain quote(single,double) but that in it then it not works.
eg. if Agent company name name provided as : David "Mike" Bela solution then it raise error as
it is not appropriate string near Mike keyword.

> Details = "AgentLastName= David "Mike" Bela solution"

How to handle for single/double quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape double quotes before output for javascript. So that it will be valid syntax. You should use something like:

```
<%= yourValue.Replace("\"", "\\\"") %>
```

Also you can use a better way of escaping with javascript:

```
var Details = "AgentCompanyName=" + $("<div/>").text("<%=yourValue%>").html();
```

With this you will create in memory DIV element, set value as text and get as escaped HTML.

Comment: Hi @Mitja Kramberger,How to handle for double quote??

Comment: Updated to escape double quotes

Comment: so we need to handle it twice as for single and double quote as I did: `<%= strString.Replace("\'","\\\'").Replace("\"","\\\"")%>` right?

Comment: You only need to do it for double quotes, so there will not be a script/syntax error. Escaping everything else will be done by javascript.